# Force reload not working in iPad Chrome browsers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am using force reload when I press back button. This is the code i am using:

```
<input type="hidden" id="refreshed" value="no">
<script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload=function(){
                        var e=document.getElementById("refreshed");
                            if(e.value=="no")
                            {
                                e.value="yes";
                            }                       
                            else  
                            {   
                                e.value="no";
                                 location.reload();
                            }
                        }
</script>
```

This is working in all the browsers and also on iPad but it is not working in iPad Google Chrome version 37.0.2062.52

Answer (score 0):

try

```
location.reload(true);
```

this should work for all iPads (as far as i know).

So why do I have to pass 'true' you might ask now. If you take a look at this definition:

```
object.reload(forcedReload);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload.
You will see that `forceReload` asks the Browser to ignore their cached data and hence **actually** reload the site (by sending a new request to the server).

Comment: Hi i tried location.reload(true) and object.reload(forcedReload); not working please help

Comment: Try window.location.href = window.location.href;